# Functional Dependency and closure

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I am learning about databases, and i came across this:

> Table P(A,B,C,D,E). The FD's are: AB->CDE, C->D, D->B, D->E. Which of
>   the following FP's are in closure of P: 1)A->C 2)C->A 3)C->B

The correct answer was marked as 3). Working backwards, i can work out that "closure of P" are all FP's in table P, but i do not know if that is correct.
I thought closures where only for attributes (showing what attributes you can get from a given attribute), rather than the whole table. Was there a mistake in the problem, or am i missing some information about closures?

Comment: A "closure" is a mathematical concept and in normalization we use the closure of (a set of FDs whose determinants are) a set of attributes and the closure of a set of FDs) in a table. Find some definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking which of those three answers are implied by the set of functional dependencies you're given. For example, AB->CDE implies AB->C, AB->D, and AB->E. Also, C->D and D->B implies C->B (the answer).

To determine which of the three possible answers are right, compute the closure of each left-hand side, and see if the possible answer is in the closure. The closure of C is BCDE.

See [Armstrong's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms)